# python: dictionary dilemma: how to properly index objects based on an attribute

Tags: python, design-patterns, data-structures, dictionary, indexing

first, an example:

> given a bunch of Person objects with
>   various attributes (name, ssn, phone,
>   email address, credit card #, etc.)
>
> now imagine the following simple
>   website:
>
> 1. uses a person's email address as unique login name
> 2. lets users edit their attributes (including their email address)
>
> if this website had tons of users,
>   then it make sense to store Person
>   objects in a dictionary indexed by
>   email address, for quick Person
>   retrieval upon login.
>
> however when a Person's email address
>   is edited, then the dictionary key for
>   that Person needs to be changed as
>   well. this is slightly yucky

im looking for suggestions on how to tackle the generic problem:

given a bunch of entities with a shared aspect. the aspect is used both for fast access to the entities and within each entity's functionality. where should the aspect be placed:

1. within each entity (not good for fast access)
2. index only (not good for each entity's functionality)
3. both within each entity and as index (duplicate data/reference)
4. somewhere else/somehow differently

the problem may be extended, say, if we want to use several indices to index the data (ssn, credit card number, etc.). eventually we may end up with a bunch of SQL tables.

im looking for something with the following properties (and more if you can think of them):

```
# create an index on the attribute of a class
magical_index = magical_index_factory(class, class.attribute)
# create an object
obj = class() 
# set the object's attribute
obj.attribute= value
# retrieve object from using attribute as index
magical_index[value] 
# change object attribute to new value
obj.attribute= new_value 
# automagically object can be retrieved using new value of attribute
magical_index[new_value]
# become less materialistic: get rid of the objects in your life
del obj
# object is really gone
magical_index[new_value]
KeyError: new_value
```

i want the object, indices, all to play nicely and seamlessly with each other.

please suggest appropriate design patterns

note:
the above example is just that, an example. an example used to portray the generic problem.
so please provide generic solutions (of course, you may choose to keep using the example when explaining your generic solution)

Comment: First, why aren't you simply using a relational database for this?  A Python dictionary means all your "tons of users" are in memory at all times, slowing things down.

Comment: @S. Lott: with modern computers, you can fit a few hundred megabytes of users into memory which is *a lot*. So it can actually be faster than using a relational database.

Comment: @Otto Allmendinger:  Absolutely true.  However, the wording of this question makes it sound like Homework.  I was probing for the reason why a database was not being used, since a database is the standard approach.  While not using a database will work, it's so rarely done that I'm puzzled why anyone would even try it -- outside doing homework, of course.

Comment: @Otto - true, unless you're using an in-memory database.  That will allow you to have your users in memory and still use proper SQL to access them.  You're reinventing a well-traveled wheel.  Another consideration is thread safety and isolation.  I usually bring large datasets into memory that way when they're read-only.  If your persons are changing, I'd go back to a relational database or add a caching solution.

Comment: @S. Lott: please note my note. i know that a relational (and persistent) db is a good solution for the example above. i dont care about website, logins or Persons. im much more interested in solutions to generic problem i posted, indexing on attributes of objects with objects and indices playing nicely with each other

Comment: @S. Lott: ill take 'sound like Homework' as a compliment on the clear wording of my problem :) i keep encountering this design problem over and over again. my homework days are long gone (the days are missed but the homework not so much (aside from se x ed. lab work))

Comment: @mlvljr: see http://tinyurl.com/yazpaot

Comment: I think you would get more/better answers if you posed the question as unit tests.

Comment: @gnibbler I wonder, has anyone here already done this, as it seems reasonable to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this.

```
class Person( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, addr, email, etc. ):
        self.observer= []
        ... etc. ...
    @property
    def name( self ): return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name( self, value ): 
        self._name= value
        for observer in self.observedBy: observer.update( self )
    ... etc. ...
```

This `observer` attribute implements an **Observable** that notifies its **Observers** of updates.   This is the list of observers that must be notified of changes.

Each attribute is wrapped with properties.  Using **Descriptors** us probably better because it can save repeating the observer notification.

```
class PersonCollection( set ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kw ):
        self.byName= collections.defaultdict(list)
        self.byEmail= collections.defaultdict(list)
        super( PersonCollection, self ).__init__( *args, **kw )
    def add( self, person ):
        super( PersonCollection, self ).append( person )
        person.observer.append( self )
        self.byName[person.name].append( person )
        self.byEmail[person.email].append( person )
    def update( self, person ):
        """This person changed.  Find them in old indexes and fix them."""
        changed = [(k,v) for k,v in self.byName.items() if id(person) == id(v) ]
        for k, v in changed:
            self.byName.pop( k )
        self.byName[person.name].append( person )
        changed = [(k,v) for k,v in self.byEmail.items() if id(person) == id(v) ]
        for k, v in changed:
            self.byEmail.pop( k )
        self.byEmail[person.email].append( person)

    ... etc. ... for all methods of a collections.Set.
```

Use collections.ABC for more information on what must be implemented.

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes

If you want "generic" indexing, then your collection can be parameterized with the names of attributes, and you can use `getattr` to get those named attributes from the underlying objects.

```
class GenericIndexedCollection( set ):
    attributes_to_index = [ ] # List of attribute names
    def __init__( self, *args, **kw ):
        self.indexes = dict( (n, {}) for n in self.attributes_to_index ]
        super( PersonCollection, self ).__init__( *args, **kw )
    def add( self, person ):
        super( PersonCollection, self ).append( person )
        for i in self.indexes:
            self.indexes[i].append( getattr( person, i )
```

Note.  To properly emulate a database, use a set not a list.  Database tables are (theoretically) sets.  As a practical matter they are unordered, and an index will allow the database to reject duplicates.  Some RDBMS's don't reject duplicate rows because -- without an index -- it's too expensive to check.

Comment: @bandana: Consider this.  The code's not really complete.  However, you can do a number of things to add that automagical function.  (1) each Person object can be tied to the owning collection.  (2) all changes can go through the collection.  #2 is the standard RDBMS approach.  #1 is the standard ORM approach.

Comment: Updating the lookup when a person changes their email address will have to be handled either inside `Person`, which makes for very awkward coupling, or by the client code, which is no better than using a simple dictionary. I'd say the simpler solution of having a separate dict key and a duplicate object property is still the way to go.

Comment: @Max S.: I'm not sure the **Observer/Observable** pattern is "very awkward coupling".

Comment: My comment was before you described doing it via the observer pattern, but I would say for a Python design, it is awkward. `Person` should not need to be touched to be placed in a container. Given Python's dynamic nature, I think it would save a lot of work to have the Collection inject the observing code dynamically.

Comment: @Max S. Agreed.  I think that Descriptors is a way to inject the observer/observable into this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, another way may be to implement the following:

1. `Attr` is an abstraction for a "value". We need this since there is no "assignment overloading" in Python (simple get / set paradigm is used as the cleanest alternative). `Attr` also acts as an "Observable".
2. `AttrSet` is an "Observer" for `Attr`s, which tracks their value changes while effectively acting as an `Attr`-to-whatever (`person` in our case) dictionary.
3. `create_with_attrs` is a factory producing what looks like a named-tuple, forwarding attribute access via supplied `Attr`s, so that `person.name = "Ivan"` effectively yields `person.name_attr.set("Ivan")` and makes the `AttrSet`s observing this `person`'s `name` appropriately rearrange their internals.

The code (tested):

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(Attribute, self).__init__()
        self._value = value
        self._notified_set = set()
    def set(self, value):
        old = self._value
        self._value = value
        for n_ch in self._notified_set:
            n_ch(old_value=old, new_value=value)
    def get(self):
        return self._value
    def add_notify_changed(self, notify_changed):
        self._notified_set.add(notify_changed)
    def remove_notify_changed(self, notify_changed):
        self._notified_set.remove(notify_changed)

class AttrSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AttrSet, self).__init__()
        self._attr_value_to_obj_set = defaultdict(set)
        self._obj_to_attr = {}
        self._attr_to_notify_changed = {}
    def add(self, attr, obj):
        self._obj_to_attr[obj] = attr
        self._add(attr.get(), obj)
        notify_changed = (lambda old_value, new_value:
                          self._notify_changed(obj, old_value, new_value))
        attr.add_notify_changed(notify_changed)
        self._attr_to_notify_changed[attr] = notify_changed
    def get(self, *attr_value_lst):
        attr_value_lst = attr_value_lst or self._attr_value_to_obj_set.keys()
        result = set()
        for attr_value in attr_value_lst:
            result.update(self._attr_value_to_obj_set[attr_value])
        return result
    def remove(self, obj):
        attr = self._obj_to_attr.pop(obj)
        self._remove(attr.get(), obj)
        notify_changed = self._attr_to_notify_changed.pop(attr)
        attr.remove_notify_changed(notify_changed)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.get())
    def _add(self, attr_value, obj):
        self._attr_value_to_obj_set[attr_value].add(obj)
    def _remove(self, attr_value, obj):
        obj_set = self._attr_value_to_obj_set[attr_value]
        obj_set.remove(obj)
        if not obj_set:
            self._attr_value_to_obj_set.pop(attr_value)
    def _notify_changed(self, obj, old_value, new_value):
        self._remove(old_value, obj)
        self._add(new_value, obj)

def create_with_attrs(**attr_name_to_attr):
    class Result(object):
        def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
            if attr_name in attr_name_to_attr.keys():
                return attr_name_to_attr[attr_name].get()
            else:
                raise AttributeError(attr_name)
        def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
            if attr_name in attr_name_to_attr.keys():
                attr_name_to_attr[attr_name].set(attr_value)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(attr_name)
        def __str__(self):
            result = ""
            for attr_name in attr_name_to_attr:
                result += (attr_name + ": "
                           + str(attr_name_to_attr[attr_name].get())
                           + ", ")
            return result
    return Result()
```

With the data prepared with

```
name_and_email_lst = [("John","email1@dot.com"),
                      ("John","email2@dot.com"),
                      ("Jack","email3@dot.com"),
                      ("Hack","email4@dot.com"),
                      ]

email = AttrSet()
name = AttrSet()

for name_str, email_str in name_and_email_lst:
    email_attr = Attribute(email_str)
    name_attr = Attribute(name_str)
    person = create_with_attrs(email=email_attr, name=name_attr)
    email.add(email_attr, person)
    name.add(name_attr, person)

def print_set(person_set):
    for person in person_set: print person
    print
```

the following pseudo-SQL snippet sequence gives:

SELECT id FROM email

```
>>> print_set(email.get())
email: email3@dot.com, name: Jack,
email: email4@dot.com, name: Hack,
email: email2@dot.com, name: John,
email: email1@dot.com, name: John,
```

SELECT id FROM email WHERE email="email1@dot.com"

```
>>> print_set(email.get("email1@dot.com"))
email: email1@dot.com, name: John,
```

SELECT id FROM email WHERE email="email1@dot.com" OR email="email2@dot.com"

```
>>> print_set(email.get("email1@dot.com", "email2@dot.com"))
email: email1@dot.com, name: John,
email: email2@dot.com, name: John,
```

SELECT id FROM name WHERE name="John"

```
>>> print_set(name.get("John"))
email: email1@dot.com, name: John,
email: email2@dot.com, name: John,
```

SELECT id FROM name, email WHERE name="John" AND email="email1@dot.com"

```
>>> print_set(name.get("John").intersection(email.get("email1@dot.com")))
email: email1@dot.com, name: John,
```

UPDATE email, name SET email="jon@dot.com", name="Jon"

WHERE id IN

SELECT id FROM email WHERE email="email1@dot.com"

```
>>> person = email.get("email1@dot.com").pop()
>>> person.name = "Jon"; person.email = "jon@dot.com"
>>> print_set(email.get())
email: email3@dot.com, name: Jack,
email: email4@dot.com, name: Hack,
email: email2@dot.com, name: John,
email: jon@dot.com, name: Jon,
```

DELETE FROM email, name WHERE id=%s

SELECT id FROM email

```
>>> name.remove(person)
>>> email.remove(person)
>>> print_set(email.get())
email: email3@dot.com, name: Jack,
email: email4@dot.com, name: Hack,
email: email2@dot.com, name: John,
```